# Moving images from doc root for added security

Tags: php, apache

My site uses bookmarklets to gather data from external sites, kinda like Pinterest. I'm concerned about security and want to move the images the bookmarklet gathers from the doc root up one level. My script has some hefty security checks in place, but I want to add this as a last line of defense.

How do I access my images within my script? Obviously using ../userimages/id/image.jpg wont work. I'm using Apache.

Thanks!

Comment: Access within the script? Or from the HTML? The PHP should still see them if you move them out of the doc root, but the browser of course cannot.

Comment: If you use different domains then you have to use domain.com/userimages/id/image.jpg. I think you see it and therefore I'm not sure I understand about why ../userimages/id/image.jpg wont work.

Comment: I mean from the HTML. My script would pull the images from outside doc root and echo them to the browser. I'm not sure I'm asking the correct question, but someone recommened that I move all images outside the doc root to beef up security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Proxy the image

You would use a proxy script to feed the images through like the following example:

```
// open the file in a binary mode
$name = '../userimages/id/image.jpg';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// you  may like to set some cache headers here

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

This example is from the PHP [manuals `fpassthru()` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php). You would save this script somewhere in your servers document root/httpdocs folder.

### "Spoofing" the URL to the image

The easiest way to give the PHP file the appearance of being an image file to a user/browser is to use Apaches `mod_rewrite`. Usually I use a URL structure something like this:

```
http://www.example.org/image-id/image.png
```

Where `image-id` is the unique identifier for that particular image. This way the file has the correct extensions of an image instead of `.php`.

Comment: So, in the example above, can $name be outside the doc root/httpdocs folder?